# Construct columns from submatrices in Matlab

Tags: matlab, octave

In Matlab, I'm trying to transform a matrix `A` to another matrix `B` such that `B`'s columns are made up of square submatrices of `A`. For example, if `A` is:

```
A = [1 1 2 2
     1 1 2 2
     3 3 4 4
     3 3 4 4];
```

I'd like `B` to be:

```
B = [1 2 3 4
     1 2 3 4
     1 2 3 4
     1 2 3 4]
```

`A` could be, say 16-by-16, and constructing `B` from 4-by-4 squares would result in `B` being 4-by-64.

Is there an efficient way to do this using `reshape` in combination with some other commands? Or some other approach? I am currently iterating in a loop, which is very slow with a large number of large source matrices.

Comment: If you the Image Processing Toolbox, can time it against `im2col()` (even though it performs a loop)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume your matrix is a bit more general, and made of 3x2 blocks:

```
A = [1 1 2 2 
     1 1 2 2
     1 1 2 2
     3 3 4 4
     3 3 4 4
     3 3 4 4
     5 5 6 6
     5 5 6 6
     5 5 6 6];

b   = [3 2];
szA = size(A);
```

Transpose, reshape, permute, reshape.

```
nb   = prod(szA./b); % Number of blocks
nelb = prod(b);      % Number of elements per block
out1 = reshape(permute(reshape(A',szA(2),b(1),szA(1)/b(1)),[2,1,3]),nelb,nb)
```

Alternatively, slower and memory intensive but more readable:

```
d1  = repmat(b(1),1,szA(1)/b(1));
d2  = repmat(b(2),1,szA(2)/b(2));
out = reshape(mat2cell(A,d1,d2)',1,nelb);
out = reshape([out{:}],nelb,nb)
```

Now, if the blocks are square, simply set `b = [2,2]` or `b = [3,3]`, etc..., or simplify the general formulation removing indexing of `b` and `prod`.

Comment: @EitanT Thanks. I should take some time and write a general case with `b` bidimensional.

Comment: No problem. I was just about to do it, but go ahead :)